# Are there algorithms for deciding or solving conjugacy in integer quaternion rings?

Tags: cryptography, quaternions, quaternion-algebras

I am doing some research on the quaternions and their role in Non-commutative cryptography. I have found a number of articles, but it is still unclear to me if there is a known solution to the Conjugacy Search Problem (CSP) or Conjugacy Decision Problem (CDP) in integer quaternion rings:

CSP: Determine whether there exists a $z$ such that $zy=xz$ for a given $(x, y) \in R$

CDP: Find a $z \in R$ such that $zy=xz$ for a given $(x, y) \in R$

Here $R$ is either the ring of Lipschitz quaternions ($\{ai+bj+ck+d\mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\}$) or the Hurwitz quaternions (which is the union of the Lipschitz quaternions with a second copy of the lattice shifted by $(\frac12, 
\frac12, \frac12, \frac12)$; i.e., where all coordinates are either integers or integers $+\frac12$).

This paper is a PKC scheme based on the Conjugacy search problem and decision problem

[Valluri and Narayan - Quaternion public-key cryptosystems](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7882612)

However, I am inclined to assume that the CSP has not been solved for the quaternions, based on the above. Does an algorithm for solving the CSP for quaternions exist?

Comment: I'm going to assume you are discussing the quaternions over $\mathbb{R}$. In this case what you are asking is essentially the conjugacy structure of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$, and it's easiest to see geometrically. Every rotation in three dimensions is a rotation by some angle around an axis, and two rotations by the same angle are conjugate via any rotation that takes one axis to the to other. The structure of the double cover doesn't change much about the conjugacy.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358830/conjugacy-in-the-quaternion-group/358837#358837

Comment: @JohnVoight Is that true for all quaternion groups, like the Lipschitz or Hurwitz?

Comment: I removed the irrelevant [algebraic-groups] and [free-groups] tags.

Comment: When you say 'the group' do you mean 'the ring'? Neither the Hurwitz nor Lipschitz quaternions form a field, so you have to be very careful using expressions like $z^{-1}$ in such a case. The question of whether there's a $z$ such that $zy=xz$ is _very_ different from the question of whether there's an invertible such $z$ (which is nearly trivial; very few Hurwitz or Lipschitz quaternions are invertible multiplicatively, after all...)

Comment: (Also, if you _do_ mean 'as a group' then the problem is trivial, because the group structure on Hurwitz or Lipschitz quaternions is the additive one, which is still commutative.)

Comment: Presuming that the question here is about conjugacy in these rings, then the problem is likely to be Complicated, by analogy with similar problems in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ for instance. I think there's an interesting question here but you need to be more specific about it.

Comment: @user157838: yes, the linear algebra approach works in the unit group of any quaternion algebra over a (computable) field.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I think you are right, I do mean conjugacy in rings, and I realize now that my question was not formulated correctly. I apologize, I am still very shaky with this kind of math. I will edit the question to be more specific

Comment: Excuse me, I would like you to clarify something. I've looked up few papers on this theme. Is it some non-commutative version of NTRU?

Comment: @LevSoukhanov Not exactly, I am just interested in the applicability of a quaternion ring to non-commutative crypto.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the question as written now follows by doing the linear algebra approach over $\mathbb{Q}$ and then scaling $z$ to get integer coefficients.

Comment: I'm currently reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02079.pdf this, hopefully it is related.

As @AchimKrause points out, currently the problem is still trivial because considered over Q. You should probably work with polynomials over H (similar to standard NTRU) to obtain interesting lattice problem.

Comment: @user157838: Just a side note: you cite some authors, but their English is so bad, that I wouldn't even bother reading their papers. But then, they got published by Hindawi, so... this should tell a lot.

Comment: @AlexM. Is Hindawi considered a reputable publisher? I looked into it briefly and found they were generally considered to be ok. Furthermore, I didn't want to discard a paper solely because of the English.

Comment: @user157838: No, Hindawi is not ok. Their peer reviewing process is... "problematic", to say the least. I constantly find emails from them in my "spam" folder, in which they promise very quick acceptance for publication. Such aggressive self-promotion should be condemned; and the promise of such quick reviewing tells a lot about its quality. Regarding the authors' English, I simply cannot understand the quoted paragraph "Regarding this [...] predicted groups": it simply makes no sense in English. Anyway, your question was about something else, so let us end this off-topic discussion here.

Comment: @AlexM. I have removed that source

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about quaternions, then you can rewrite the equation $y = z^{-1}xz$ as $zy - xz = 0$ which is $\mathbb{R}$-linear in $z$. Therefore both problems can be solved quite easily using linear algebra. (I.e. introduce real indeterminates $z_1, \ldots, z_4$ via $z = z_1 + i z_2 + j z_3 + k z_4$, insert into the latter formula and obtain linear system for $z_1, \ldots, z_4.$

If you are talking about quaternion group, then it's even easier as you can just test all eight elements.

Comment: What about the Libschitz or Hurwitz groups?

Comment: I hope that you aren't missing the fact that the OP is working over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AlexM.: The OP changed the question. It was not originally about the integral case.